# React-native with Firebase FCM not working

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-fcm

I have done the following changes:

How is send notifications, using firebase-admin and getting successful result:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(
        "token as string",
        {
        notification: {
            title: 'title here',
            body: 'body here'
            }
        },
        {
            priority: "high",
            contentAvailable: true,
            timeToLive: 2419200
        });
```

React-native code, this is when the application is in the foreground:

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkToken().then((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      // write to db
    });
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log(remoteMessage);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

I have the GoogleService-Info.plist file in the ios folder, I have uploaded the APNs in the firebase console + teamid + appid.

Following changes in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
....
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

[FIRApp configure];
```

I am not receiving any notification while the app runs in the foreground, there must be something wrong with the way I am sending (probably I have the wrong options) or, what I have in react-native is wrongly configured, not sure. I am trying to do it only for IOS for now.

Any info or solution would be helpful.

Comment: Can you check **PushNotification.onNotification=(message)=> {}**, import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

Comment: Are background messages working? Make sure you followed every step of this https://rnfirebase.io/ and this https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage and this https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup. Also make sure to test messages on a real device since fcm will NEVER work on Ios simulator as stated in the docs. I found this pretty hard to integrate too when I first did this.

Comment: Thank you for this, I have followed the documentation from above, couldn't get it working until now. I'll keep on trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it by running a clean run on an actual device.

Answer (score 2):

React native firebase do not show notification when the app is in foreground, so what I have done is, I am using a different library to handle foreground notification. I am using **react-native-push-notification**.\

**For Android**

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
import PushNotificationIos from '@react-native-community/push-notification-ios';

useEffect(() => {
    checkToken().then((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      // write to db
    });
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      PushNotification.localNotification({
        message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        bigPictureUrl: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
        smallIcon: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
      });
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

For iOS:
For iOS you have to install **@react-native-community/push-notification-ios** 
Also follow all the native installation steps as suggested in document.
Then write the following code

```
PushNotification.configure({
    onNotification: (notification) => {
      if (notification) {
        console.log(notification);
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // To display notification when app is in foreground
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage) => {
      PushNotificationIos.addNotificationRequest({
        message: remoteMessage.notification.body,
        title: remoteMessage.notification.title,
        bigPictureUrl: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
        smallIcon: remoteMessage.notification.android.imageUrl,
      });
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: I know that with firebase I can't show the notifications, I am using a different package for that Notifee, the problem for me is that I don't get the message here:
`messaging().onMessage(async (remoteMessage)` I don't receive the message in `remoteMessage` param.

Comment: is this happening for both android and ios?

Comment: I haven't tested on android it all, only on ios.

Comment: Can you add the notification object which you are sending from backend?

Comment: I am using admin-firebase, the object is in the question, here: `{ notification: { title: 'title here', body: 'body here' } }`

Comment: Did you try sending the notification with data tag, instead of notification tag? like this **{data: { title: 'here', body: 'here' }};**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240823/discussion-between-akshay-shenoy-and-nicolae-maties).

Answer (score 1):

1st you need to get the messaging permission

```
async function requestUserPermission() {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
  
    if (enabled) {
      console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a channel:

```
const createFCMChannel = async () => {
    const channelId = await notifee.createChannel({
      id: 'default',
      name: 'Default Channel',
    });
};
```

You can just call this method which will call "displayNotification" from notifee

```
function onMessageReceived(message) {
    notifee.displayNotification(message.notification);
}
```

you can use these methods in useEffect when your app starts:

```
useEffect(() => {
    createFCMChannel();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission();
    messaging().onMessage(onMessageReceived);
    messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(onMessageReceived);
}, []);
```

Comment: I know this, the problem for me is that I don't receive the message, I know how Notifee works. Thank you for this though.

Answer (score 0):

You can control and print notification data directly from AppDelegate file. It allows quicker debugging process as you bypass your app logic and play with the data at the first incoming door. This way, you will find out where is the problem - server side (notification data structure etc.) or app logic/local handling process.
Just play with this sample code part in Appdelegate.m file:

```
Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo) 

  With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
  [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];
  FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);
  Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        completionHandler(.NoData)
          [[FIRMessaging messaging] appDidReceiveMessage:userInfo];

  ...

  // Print full message.
  NSLog(@"%@", userInfo);
```

And as a rule of thumb, check this from Apple developer page about structure and parameters: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to solve this issue

1. You can check whether the notifican permission is granted or not?
2. Check if you have set the both foreground and background notifications?
3. Uninstall the app and reinstall it.
4. Clean run with real device.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).